# How can I dynamically limit data showing in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have this ng-repeat that I show split over three rows here for clarity:

```
ng-repeat="row in phs.phrasesView = 
           (phs.phrases | orderBy:phs.phrasesOrderBy[phs.phrasesOrderById]
           .key:phs.phrasesSortDirectionId == 1)">
```

On my form I have a field `phs.keywordRange`

Is there a way that I can make it so the rows returned are filtered as follows:

- When phs.keywordRange is null or empty string, all rows are shown
- When phs.keywordRange is `A` then only rows where row.keyword starts with `A` are shown
- When phs.keywordRange is `ABC` then only rows where row.keyword starts with `ABC` are shown

Comment: You can always build your own filter. [Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) already does almost exactly this so that would be a good place to start if you need help figuring out how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own filter, like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4k6kmLd/).
Changing the $scope.keywordRange will update the list accordingly.

as shortcut:

```
.filter('keywordRange', function() {
   return function(value, keyword) {

   var out = [];

   if(!keyword) {
     return value;
   }

   for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
     if(value[i].startsWith(keyword)){
       out.push(value[i]);
     }
   }

   return out;
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.keywordRange = 'ti';

  $scope.lines = [
    'rest1', 'rest2', 'tiago', 'pedro', 'america'
  ];
}
```

and the html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="line in lines | keywordRange:keywordRange">

     <p>{{line}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out and update your answer soon.

Comment: I am getting this error:  value[i].startsWith is not a function. I think it's because my rows are objects and each object has a property .keyword. So I need to take this into account.

Comment: Yes, use value[i].keyword